# Angular/RxJS combineLatest missing emitted data

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have an Angular component that displays data from a socket. This view also has filtering and search. The filter/search are Angular form controls.

I used combineLatest to combine all the filter/search form control's valueChanges observables (they have startWith('')) and my socket observable. This helps to handle data updates and filter updates in one convenient place.

Since combineLatest waits for all Observables to emit at least once...The issue I am having is that the socket observable emitted a few times before the filter/search observables have set up and emitted their first time, thus I missed a few data events from socket that are needed.

To keep things simple I created a simple example with timers below.

```
 combineLatest([
            timer(0, 1000),
            timer(10000, 1000)
        ]).subscribe(([timerOne, timerTwo]) => {
            console.log(`Timer One Latest: ${timerOne}, Timer Two Latest: ${timerTwo}`);
        })
```

The first time combineLatest emits, timer one is at 9 already and timer two is at 0. This is same case with my Angular view, the socket events have emitted a few times before combineLatest is emitted the first time. I explored buffering or delaying first timer, but nothing really worked.

I would like to know if there is a way to ensure no observable data inside a combineLatest is missed?
Perhaps, on first combineLatest emit, emit all timerOne values. Or, trigger combineLatest x times that timerOne emitted...or maybe I am just not using the correct operator.

Comment: you can emit once for every source with the help of `startWith('')` and it sounds like it should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is not with `combineLatest`. Your problem comes from the fact that your socket `Observable` will never emit previous events to new subscribers. When you combine regular observables all the previous values they emitted are "lost" since there were no subscribers when the values were emitted. What you want to do is to make your socket into a "hot observable" and use something like `ReplaySubject` to share all the previous events with new subscribers. Only then your `combineLatest` will receive the values that socked fired before the subscription happened.

In other words, messages sent by socket never reach `combineLatest`, because it subscribes too late. To make sure that all previous messages arrive, you need to change socket observable type into something that shares previous messages e.g. `ReplaySubject`.